# Is it possible to sum the expression column in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

I am stuck in a scenario where client needed to do sum of column which is containing calculated values(Expressions) which are calculated at the run-time (At the time of generating report).

I suggested client to calculate this column at database side and return this column to SSRS dataset but due to some circumstances it is not possible.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have comment access So Iam not able to ask you more details. You can `SUM` up the calculated expression in `SSRS` AS you didn't mention how it looks.I am getting one example.

If this is how your normal cell of calculation looks,

```
  =Fields!FirstCol.Value+Fields!SecondCol.Value
```

Then the `SUM` can be

```
   =SUM(Fields!FirstCol.Value)+SUM(Fields!SecondCol.Value)
```

And if you added the `calulatedColumn` in the `Dataset` itself then it becomes more simple as you just have to do as,

```
   =SUM(Fields!CalculatedCol.Value)
```